# JavaScript Backwards Countdown with 1 second pause

Tags: javascript, timer

Can someone let me know where I'm going going? I'm just trying to count down from a given number in the code and print to screen 1, pause for 1 second, print 2, pause for 1 second, print 3, pause for 1 second...

I tried using `sleep(1000)` but always get a 'sleep undefined' error and when I use the below code the `setTimeout(1000)` returns "invalid arguement"

```
var i;

function timer()
{

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    setTimeout(1000);
    document.write(i);

}



}
timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) doesn't work like that, it is not the same as sleep in java or any other language

you can use something like

```
var i = 0;
function timer(){
    document.write(i++);
    if(i >= 10){
        clearInterval(timerId)
    }
}

var timerId = setInterval(timer, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for setTimeout are (functionToCall, time).
This is because setTimeout (like most functions in JavaScript) is asynchronous: while it waits for one second, it does other stuff in the program. Once the time is up, it comes back and runs the function.

```
var message = "Hello, World!";

var timer = function timer() { 
    document.write(message); 
};

setInterval(timer, 1000);     //will print 'Hello, World!' after one second
```